# Matinee movement track on multiple actors

Tags: movement, unreal-4

I have some different actors (all spheres) that i want to move along a path (circular) and they also need to roll when they are moving, so i tried this using matinees movement track and attached all spheres to one parent (the first sphere), but all the the other spheres move relative to the first one so if i rotate the childs will rotate on the axis of the parent and not around there own axis. and also they wont follow a path.

would this be possible using matinee? or what would be the best way to achieve this?

i thought of making a parent in the middle of the circular path and rotate around that axis but then the wont roll when moving, so maybe i should make a rolling animation separately. which will triggered when they move?

the spheres will not constantly move, what i want to make is sort of a 3d gallery where the focus is on one sphere and if you want to see the next one, roll that sphere toward you and the other one away towards the background.